# "ifconfig" shows nothing on Genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

I've tried several virtual devices on genymotion, including a custom phone with android 4.3 and google nexus 7 with android 4.4, none of them works with `ifconfig`. This is what I do:

1. adb shell
2. su
3. ifconfig

It shows nothing. Is it a bug? Is there any other way to show all the network interfaces and IP addresses?

Comment: try "ifconfig eth0", or use "netcfg" to list all available devices then choose the appropriate one  -- also try -- adb shell netcfg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. adb shell
2. su
3. **netcfg**

Hope this helps! :)